# Collectiongroup query returns nothing in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a to-do app in firebase.
I want to return all the projects that my currently signed in user is particpiating in.
However, I don't get nothing back when looping over the returned query.

I suspect there is no document that matches my criteria but there are documents that should match. The problem can only be in the code..

My database is setup like this:

- Projects

  - ProjectDocument

    - Deadline Date
    - Description

      - Users

        - UserDocument

          - uid
          - email
          - name

A couple of weeks ago, the given query worked but now...
Anyone that can help me out?

My code:

```
  const myUID = sessionStorage.getItem('user');
  const queryProjects = query(collectionGroup(db, "users"), where('uid', '==', `${myUID}`));
  const myProjects = await getDocs(queryProjects);
  const test = myProjects.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc);
    // Nothing appears in my console
  });
```

Screenshots of my database:
[image: main collection]
[image: subcollection]

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it.

Comment: Alex Mamo, I added the screenshots :)

Comment: What is the exact value of `myUID`?

Comment: myUID is the current uid of the person who is logged in at the moment. So in that case the current logged in user only sees the documents where his UID matches in each to do item that his credentials are saved. You see what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Are you able to log myUID on console?

Comment: I stored the UID in sessionstorage when the user is logged in

Comment: Can you check with hardcoded `UID` and check if you are able to get any outputs?